# Is there a defined way to create a commit history for Git

Tags: history, git

I have been working (alone) on an [open-source project](http://nero.sf.net) without using any sort of formal version control.

I recently started using Git and [GitHub](https://github.com/corvec/NERO-Character-Creator) for this project and am wondering if it is possible for me to build a code/commit history based off of the archived, older versions of the code that I have.

Development thus far has been solely linear. It's progressed from version 0.1 through 0.9.6.3 without any branches.

I've looked through the Git User Manual and the closest thing I can think of would involve making labeled or named commits for each previous version.

What is the best way to handle this? Do I need to create a new repository and start pushing labeled commits into it, ending with the current version? Is it possible to change the dates of existing commits? Is there a more straightforward way?

I'm using Git on Windows XP (native, not Cygwin), but if it would be easier I can set it up on my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are doing the import is by setting up a git repo anywhere you want on the workstation where you have access to the sources, and point `GIT_WORK_TREE` to where you can load the successive version of your code base.

From there, you can `git add` and `git commit` the different versions of your code base, updating `GIT_WORK_TREE` to point to the right versions.

Use `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` for each import in order to set the right author's name and date. (See [Environment Variables in Git](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/#_environment_variables))

Comment: Is that all I have to do? I think I'm missing something...
My current git repo is set up in ~/workspace/NCC.  
The older versions are all in ~/workspace/nerocc/history.  
The first one is ~/workspace/nerocc/history/0.1_2009-08-28.  In Git Bash, I ran the following commands:

`$ cd workspace/NCC
$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=2009-08-28
$ GIT_WORK_TREE=~/workspace/nerocc/history/0.1_2009-08-28
$ git add ~/workspace/nerocc/history/0.1_2009-08-28
fatal: '<path>' is outside repository
$ git commit`

That gives me a message about the untracked files in the current directory...

Comment: @coverc: I am not sure a simple `GIT_WORK_TREE=...` is enough, depending on your shell. You should do an `export GIT_WORK_TREE=...` in order to make sure the value of that variable will be available for other processes (like the `git` command you are launching just after that).

Comment: That's definitely what I was missing! I got it to work as follows, in git bash: 
`$ cd workspace/NCC
$ export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
$ export GIT_WORK_TREE
$ GIT_WORK_TREE=~/workspace/nerocc/history/0.1_2009-08-28
$ GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=$(date -d 2009/08/28)
$ git commit .
$ git push`
Thanks!